# How to link Bitbucket Pull Requests from commit text messages in SourceTree?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Upon **MERGE** of **Pull Requests** in **Bitbucket**, the git commit messages in your target branch look like so:

> Merge pull request #PRNUMBER in PROJNAME/REPONAME from sourcebranchname to
>   targetbranchname
>
> - commit '61ead4d30bla498543cblaef03fdf0be41fblub7':   added rootId property to allow filtering ...

The URL scheme for showing Pull Requests in Bitbucket looks like this:

> http://bitbuckethost:port/projects/PROJNAME/repos/REPONAME/pull-requests/PRNUMBER

In **SourceTree**, advanced **repo settings** allow you to link commit message patterns to URLs.

So far, I fail to setup a suitable regex pattern and don't know how to refer matched tokens in URL. Does someone know, how to do that or know of a complete reference documenting how to do such with SourceTree?

Answer (score 1):

1. go to *advanced* repo settings in SourceTree
2. *add* new commit text link
3. choose *Replacement Type* **Other**
4. set *regex pattern* to `(Merge pull request #)(\d*)` - this will match the commit text including PR id, putting the text in first token and id number in second
5. set *URL link* to `http://bitbuckethost:port/projects/PROJNAME/repos/REPONAME/pull-requests/$2` - this makes use of second matching token